# What is the Maximum Number of XML Records to Send to SSRS

Tags: xml, oracle, reporting-services

I have a situation where my source system is an Oracle database. The number of records which are returned from a standard query from SSRS to the Oracle DB is about 4 million rows. So I do not use an Oracle connector, we have a product on the Oracle server which receives the query, queries the oracle server, converts that to XML, and sends it back to the SSRS Report server.

The SSRS Report server then hangs and the service needs to be restarted, I think my main question is there a maximum number of rows SSRS can process at one time or is there a way to break the returned XML into smaller batch sizes maybe.

Comment: If you are transferring 4 million rows and each row is, for example, 500 bytes then you are going to be transferring ~2Gb of data. Depending on your network that is going to be slow and depending on how you handle it it may crash your application if you are trying to read (and process) 2GB into memory. This question is almost impossible to answer as there is insufficient information on what you are doing or where the problem lies.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, how can I determine the size of each of these rows are returned

Comment: Could I ask this question is there a maximum XML file size that SSRS is able to handle?